# Django QuerySet arguments manipulation

Tags: django

I'm trying to get into bug hunting. I found the following requests on one of bug bounty programs:

```
httx://example.com/api/news/?filter=%7B%22date_end__gt%22:%222024-02-14T13:52:45.646Z%22,%22check_news%22:true%7D&order_by=-important_news,-date_start
```

It looks familiar to me since I'm a coder. I recognized django QuerySet which I can manipulate. I found out it's possible to add `exclude` parameter and it works correctly. Unfortunately adding `extra` didn't work out.

I suppose the code processing these requests looks like:

```
for op, val in query.items():
    if op == 'filter':
        ret = News.objects.filter(**val)
    elif op == 'exclude': 
        . . .
```

Could you please tell me if it worth to invest my time to? Is there a way to exploit this behavior?

Comment: The querystring-queryset mapping is similar to what is implemented in the Django admin, so I thought the following link may give some directions: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2.4/#restricted-filters-in-admin-interface)